# Need help figuring out what this xcopy command does

Tags: cmd, windows-10, xcopy

Can anyone tell me what this command is doing on CMD:

```
xcopy f2 ..\desktop /d /e /f /i /l
```

**My objective**: Figuring out how to use xcopy to move one directory with all its contents to another directory located on my PC. In this case f2 is a directory that has x3 directories inside that I want to move using this command to another location on my PC.

**Miscellaneous**: I know it's doing something because the number of bytes free on my PC has decreased.

Thanks kindly.

Comment: why you have choose other answer?

Comment: I actually was clicking around, my bad. If you like I can change it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command do nothing on filesystem.

The parameter `/l` simulate only a copy.

The xcopy command don't move but "copy".

For copy a directory to another place you can use:

```
xcopy f2 ..\desktop\f2 /d /f /e /i
```

you must specify the destination directory otherwise all files in "f2" are copied on the desktop.

to know what the other parameters do you can use `xcopy /?`

Comment: Why did the number of bytes increase then? I ran this command more than once and I checked my desktop but no files. It did decrease the number of bytes on my PC but I thought that at least it would have moved the files of my previous directory to my desktop. Have I done something dumb? Did I just performed a ghost copy?

Comment: if the command you have executed is that and there are no spaces or other errors you must be sure that you have not copied anything. The disk space changes all the time due to the numerous processes running on the SO.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention yourself, the command copies the entire `f2` directory into the `desktop` directory, located in the parent directory (`..`).

The switches are all mentioned in the `xcopy /?` helpfile, but there is something I don't understand: the `/F` switches shows completely what's going on, it shows every file from beginning to destination, as in this example:

```
Prompt>xcopy /F test.txt blabla\
C:\Temp_Folder\test.txt -> C:\Temp_Folder\blabla\test.txt
```

So, if you run that command, you can see for yourself what it is doing on screen, so why do you ask? Is this command somewhere in a scheduled task, that you can't see the result? (In that case, you might redirect the output to a logfile)

Comment: Why did the number of bytes increase then? I ran this command more than once and I checked my desktop but no files. It did decrease the number of bytes on my PC but I thought that at least it would have moved the files of my previous directory to my desktop. Have I done something dumb? Did I just performed a ghost copy?

Comment: Maybe the result of this command is appended to some logfile. As it gets growing, the free space of your PC decreases.

Comment: Got it. Thanks nonetheless.